# Encryption going a bit haywire

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim A As String
    Dim B As String
    Dim C As String
    Dim D As String
    Dim EE As String
    Dim F As String
    Dim G As String
    Dim H As String
    Dim I As String
    Dim J As String
    Dim K As String
    Dim L As String
    Dim M As String
    Dim N As String
    Dim O As String
    Dim P As String
    Dim Q As String
    Dim R As String
    Dim S As String
    Dim T As String
    Dim U As String
    Dim V As String
    Dim W As String
    Dim X As String
    Dim Y As String
    Dim Z As String

    Dim la As String
    Dim lb As String
    Dim lc As String
    Dim ld As String
    Dim le As String
    Dim lf As String
    Dim lg As String
    Dim lh As String
    Dim li As String
    Dim lj As String
    Dim lk As String
    Dim ll As String
    Dim lm As String
    Dim ln As String
    Dim lo As String
    Dim lp As String
    Dim lq As String
    Dim lr As String
    Dim ls As String
    Dim lt As String
    Dim lu As String
    Dim lv As String
    Dim lw As String
    Dim lx As String
    Dim ly As String
    Dim lz As String

    Private Sub btnGen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGen.Click
        If txtMessage.Text = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text Box 'Message' is empty")
            Ok = False
        End If
        If txtKey.Text = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text Box 'Key' is empty")
            Ok = False
        End If
        If txtShuffle.Text = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text Box 'Shuffle' is empty")
            Ok = False
        End If
        OkNum = IsNumeric(txtShuffle.Text)
        If OkNum = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Text Box 'Shuffle' is not numeric")
            Ok = False
        End If

        If Ok = True Then
            Message = txtMessage.Text
            Key = txtKey.Text
            Shuffle = txtShuffle.Text
            ShufCount = 0
            A = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            B = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            C = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            D = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            EE = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            F = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            G = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            H = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            I = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            J = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            K = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            L = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            M = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            N = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            O = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            P = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            Q = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            R = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            S = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            T = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            U = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            V = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            W = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            X = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            Y = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            Z = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1

            la = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lb = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lc = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            ld = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            le = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lf = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lg = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lh = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            li = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lj = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lk = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            ll = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lm = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            ln = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lo = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lp = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lq = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lr = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            ls = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lt = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lu = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lv = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            'MessageBox.Show(lv)
            ShufCount += 1
            lw = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lx = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            ly = Key.Chars(ShufCount)
            ShufCount += 1
            lz = Key.Chars(ShufCount)

            Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
            dict.Add(0, A)
            dict.Add(1, B)
            dict.Add(2, C)
            dict.Add(3, D)
            dict.Add(4, EE)
            dict.Add(5, F)
            dict.Add(6, G)
            dict.Add(7, H)
            dict.Add(8, I)
            dict.Add(9, J)
            dict.Add(10, K)
            dict.Add(11, L)
            dict.Add(12, M)
            dict.Add(13, N)
            dict.Add(14, O)
            dict.Add(15, P)
            dict.Add(16, Q)
            dict.Add(17, R)
            dict.Add(18, S)
            dict.Add(19, T)
            dict.Add(20, U)
            dict.Add(21, V)
            dict.Add(22, W)
            dict.Add(23, X)
            dict.Add(24, Y)
            dict.Add(25, Z)

            dict.Add(26, la)
            dict.Add(27, lb)
            dict.Add(28, lc)
            dict.Add(29, ld)
            dict.Add(30, le)
            dict.Add(31, lf)
            dict.Add(32, lg)
            dict.Add(33, lh)
            dict.Add(34, li)
            dict.Add(35, lj)
            dict.Add(36, lk)
            dict.Add(37, ll)
            dict.Add(38, lm)
            dict.Add(39, ln)
            dict.Add(40, lo)
            dict.Add(41, lp)
            dict.Add(42, lq)
            dict.Add(43, lr)
            dict.Add(44, ls)
            dict.Add(45, lt)
            dict.Add(46, lu)
            dict.Add(47, lv)
            dict.Add(48, lw)
            dict.Add(49, lx)
            dict.Add(50, ly)
            dict.Add(51, lz)

            If radEn.Checked = True Then
                MessageBox.Show("Running radEn")
                Dim Encrypted As String = ""
                Dim MessLength As Integer = Message.Length()
                Dim WhileCounter As Integer = 0

                While WhileCounter < MessLength
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "A" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(0)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "B" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(1)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "C" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(2)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "D" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(3)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "E" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(4)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "F" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(5)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "G" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(6)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "H" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(7)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "I" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(8)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "J" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(9)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "K" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(10)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "L" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(11)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "M" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(12)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "N" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(13)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "O" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(14)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "P" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(15)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "Q" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(16)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "R" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(17)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "S" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(18)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "T" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(19)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "U" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(20)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "V" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(21)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "W" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(22)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "X" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(23)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "Y" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(24)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "Z" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(25)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "a" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(26)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "b" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(27)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "c" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(28)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "d" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(29)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "e" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(30)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "f" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(31)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "g" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(32)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "h" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(33)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "i" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(34)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "j" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(35)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "k" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(36)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "l" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(37)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "m" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(38)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "n" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(39)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "o" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(40)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "p" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(41)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "q" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(42)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "r" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(43)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "s" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(44)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "t" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(45)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "u" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(46)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "v" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(47)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "w" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(48)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "x" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(49)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "y" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(50)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = "z" Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + dict(51)
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = " " Then
                        Encrypted = Encrypted + " "
                    End If

                    WhileCounter += 1
                End While



                FinalMessage = Encrypted
                Editor.Show()
                Editor.txtEdit.Clear()
                Editor.txtEdit.ReadOnly = True
                Editor.txtEdit.Text = FinalMessage
            ElseIf radDe.Checked = True Then
                Dim Decrypted As String = ""
                Dim MessLength As Integer = Message.Length()
                Dim WhileCounter As Integer = 0
                Dim LazyCounter As Integer = 0

                While WhileCounter < MessLength
                    LazyCounter = 0
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "A"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "B"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "C"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "D"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "E"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "F"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "G"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "H"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "I"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "J"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "K"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "L"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "M"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "N"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "O"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "Q"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "R"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "S"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "T"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "U"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "V"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "W"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "X"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "Y"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "Z"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "a"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "b"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "c"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "d"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "e"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "f"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "g"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "h"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "i"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "j"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "k"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "l"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "m"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "n"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "o"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "p"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "q"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "r"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "s"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "t"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "u"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "v"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "w"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "x"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "y"
                    End If
                    LazyCounter += 1
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = dict(LazyCounter) Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + "z"
                    End If
                    If Message.Chars(WhileCounter) = " " Then
                        Decrypted = Decrypted + " "
                    End If

                    LazyCounter = 0
                    WhileCounter += 1
                End While

                FinalMessage = Decrypted



                Editor.Show()
                Editor.txtEdit.Clear()
                Editor.txtEdit.ReadOnly = True
                Editor.txtEdit.Text = FinalMessage
            End If
            ShufCount = 0
            While dict.Count > ShufCount
                dict.Remove(ShufCount)
                ShufCount += 1
            End While
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Im close to making this work. However sometimes decrypting the message causes me some issues. If I make my message and key the same, which for now im just using the "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm". Decrypting it turns out to be "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdef..." which is what its supposed to do and works just fine.

But if I put "MY NAME IS BOB" for the message and use the same key. After Decrypting it, it turns out to be "MZ NAME IT BOB". Also "Jims Cat is Ugly" encrypted and then decrypted turns into "Jjnt Cbu jt Vhmz" .I've tried looking for simple errors I might of made, such as assigning C = 3 when it should be 2. Sometimes, like the first one, its just 1 or two letters. Others, like the second, and unreadable. Anyone got any insight or any idea as to why this isn't working?

Comment: I went cross-eyed trying to read that.  When code gets that repetitive, it generally means you've taken a wrong turning somewhere.  Would it not be possible to replace all your `Dim A As String`, `Dim B As String` etc. with some sort of list or array and loop through them?

Comment: May I ask why? Is this for school or something for fun (I hope)?

Comment: @Igor boredum at school =P xD

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Your probably right, but im not to familiar with Arrays quite yet. This has just been the way I've been doing it for now. But as I said, I've checked that particular section of the code at least 6 six times by now. Not saying its impossible that I made a mistake somewhere, just saying I don't think its likely. But even if I were to make them an array, wouldn't I still need to plug all A-z into the array? So it would still be long and repetitive? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thats not encryption it is a (very crude) cipher.  Some letters are going to get swapped twice (guessing - the processing code isnt shown).  First, letter 2 (Y) is switched to B, then when processing the B in Bob it changes the first B again

Comment: @Plutonix I thought ciphers were encryption? Whats the difference? Also, what do you mean my code processing B twice? Is it doing something like M = A then M = M.replace("A","B").replace("B","C") and its outputting C for example?

Comment: Nonono, do not use `+` when concatenating strings. You will eventually run into problems. Use the ampersand `&` instead.